# how i can change language on System.Speech.Synthesis?

Tags: c#, speech

I write Code and i use on it "System.Speech.Synthesis" library but its on default only English So How i can change it to French or other languages ??

This Part of my Code :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer()) {  synth.Speak("Welcome To Calcualtor"); }
}

     }
```

i Search on internet how change it but i dont know much about c# 
this whats i [found](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx)

so i appreciate any help or suggestions from you guys and thanks already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select a pre-installed voice that will speak in you chosen language.

I'm almost sure that the default language of your computer/server will be used if you don't select any voice.

```
using (SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    synthesizer.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

    // this
    synthesizer.SelectVoice("ScanSoft Virginie_Dri40_16kHz");

    // or this
    synthesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Neutral, VoiceAge.NotSet, 0, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-fr"));

    synthesizer.Speak("Bonjour !");
}
```